# onAuthStateChanged now returns null in react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

For the past couple of weeks, my code worked fine when I used onAuthStateChanged to redirect the logged-in users to the home page after the splash screen. However, as of this week onAuthStateChanged returns a null auth.currentUser and does not redirect the logged-in user appropriately.

I am following the directions from firebase docs, and I can't seem to figure out why it does not work suddenly.

I am using react-native 0.71.3 with Expo 48.0.0

This code fails with reloading the app after the authenticated user is logged in.

```js
const auth = getAuth(app);

useEffect(() => {

  let subscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    console.log(auth.currentUser)  //returns null now
    if (user) {
      navigation.navigate("Root")
    } 
  });
  
return subscriber
}, [])
```

Comment: Did you recently update expo?

Comment: Yes, but Expo 47 had the same issues. It was not with the expo update. I tried to see if Expo 48 would fix this issue, but it did not.

Comment: Which firebase package are you using?

Comment: `null` means there is no authenticated user. You need to complete the authentication flow properly to get a `currentUser`.

Comment: Yes, this is after refreshing with an authenticated user.

Comment: "firebase": "^9.17.1",

Answer (score 2):

The default persistence is depricated so you need to reaplce it with the new react native asyncStorage.

In the firebase config file initialize auth and app like the code below.

```js
import {
  initializeApp,
  getApp,
  getApps
} from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getAuth
} from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  getReactNativePersistence,
  initializeAuth,
} from 'firebase/auth/react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

const firebaseConfig = {
  //config here
};

// Initialize Firebase
let app, auth;

if (!getApps().length) {
  try {
    app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    auth = initializeAuth(app, {
      persistence: getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error initializing app: ' + error);
  }
} else {
  app = getApp();
  auth = getAuth(app);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, now I see why it is important to read breaking changes every time we upgrade expo SDK