# Firebase V9 - "INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition" on React Native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am developing a react native app with firebase authentication using V9 SDK. Everything is working fine except when I want to add persistence in authentication.

I've tried multiple ways to add it but none of them worked. Bellow, there is the latest and cleanest way I've tried. The problem is that when I use this code (to add persistence otherwise it works fine), I have the error :

> INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, browserLocalPersistence, setPersistence } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
  measurementId: "XXX",
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

export const auth = getAuth(app);

// Enable Firebase persistence
const enableFirebasePersistence = async () => {
  try {
    await setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors here
    console.log("Error enabling Firebase persistence:", error);
  }
};

// Call the function to enable persistence
enableFirebasePersistence();

export const db = getFirestore(app);
export default app;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer on another posts trying thousands different keywords lol.

It appears that the problem is coming from new version of expo. Using AsyncStorage on initializing firebase works for me. Here is the link to the post where I've found the solution : [onAuthStateChanged now returns null in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716512/onauthstatechanged-now-returns-null-in-react-native)

Comment: can you please share your code that what you did to solve that problem, cause i am facing the same